# Application has generated an exception that can't be handled

Tags: .net

Getting this error when transferring a program to a new domain and new servers, and only for a few users:

```
"Request for the permission of type System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 failed."

at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckHelper(PermissionSet grantedSet, PermissionSet deniedSet, CodeAccessPermission demand, PermissionToken permToken)
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(PermissionToken permToken, CodeAccessPermission demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Int32 checkFrames, Int32 unrestrictedOverride)
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.set_Title(String value)
at mainForm.InitializeComponent() in C:\MyProjects\DTSExecuter.root\DTSExecuter\DWMaintenance\mainForm.vb:line 88
at mainForm..ctor() in C:\MyProjects\DTSExecuter.root\DTSExecuter\DWMaintenance\mainForm.vb:line 16
at mainForm.Main() in C:\MyProjects\DTSExecuter.root\DTSExecuter\DWMaintenance\mainForm.vb:line 4
```

My machine runs the application just fine, as do other users, but there are a small few users who get 
an "Application has generated an exception that could not be handled." error box, and when debugging it returns the above error. This is a legacy application that we may not have access to source code for, and it just changed connection strings within the internal connection manager. That was the only change to the application other than running on a new domain.

Comment: FileIOPermission is clear. Your users have no permission to use some files required by the application.

Comment: Are those having issues on newer operating systems by chance? the error as mentioned is pretty clear here. This is permissions all the way.

Comment: All of the files used in the application are stored on the network share along with the .exe file, and all users have full control permissions for those folders. Could there be something else I'm missing?

Comment: You should add a question, otherwise it may be difficult to know what you want to know. This is a *question* and answer forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run in to this before myself. If the starting location for the Open/SaveFileDialog is a network path and the account running the application does not have permissions to read the network path it will throw this exception.

Just set the value of [InitalDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) to something safe (like `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)`) and it should fix the problem.

---

After re-reading the question, I see you can not change the source. The there is only two things I can suggest. The users who are having problems, have them use a shortcut to launch the program and set the Working Directory to a local path. If the original programmer did not set a `InitalDirectory` it will default to the working directory.

The other thing to check is you said you moved to a new domain, make sure the users have permissions to whatever folder the program is trying to talk to. Perhaps the permissions where not migrated over correctly.

---

After seeing [the comment in XPD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699882/application-has-generated-an-exception-that-cant-be-handled/16700440#comment24038481_16700371) I think this is what is happening:

1. A user connects to `\\Foo\Bar\` and manually enters a username and password.
2. The user starts the program from the network share `\\Foo\Bar\Baz.exe`
3. The program loads itself in to RAM and executes with the working directory of `\\Foo\Bar\`
4. The loader sees that the program needs to run elevated and it gives a UAC prompt and re-executes the program as a new credential
5. The user opens a open file dialog and no `InitalDirectory` was set for the dialog. it uses the working directory set from step #4.
6. Because the new credential from step #4 does NOT get a copy of the security token generated from step #1, the AppDomain of the program does not have rights to access `\\Foo\Bar\`.

   1. If the user had the dialog open and they navigated to the path by hand it would have re-prompted for credentials.
   2. However, because the InitalPath was set to the working directory the error happens before the UI can ask for credentials and a FileIOPermission execption is thrown.

There is four ways to fix this, in decreasing order of preferred options.

1. Modify the original program to use the user's desktop as the `InitialDirectory` for the dialog
2. Modify the working directory of the program when it starts (like via starting from a shortcut and specifying it)
3. Modify permissions on `\\Foo\Bar` so that the user does not need to manually enter credentials to connect to it.
4. Disable UAC.

Comment: I finally got this to work by moving the application to the Desktop, then in Properties > Compatibility for the .exe checking the "Run this program as an administrator" for all users. That seems to have fixed the permissions error.

Comment: +1 for working this out from the slightest of clues! Btw, I believe you need a "NOT" in this sentence: "6. Because the new credential from step #4 does NOT get a copy of the security token generated from step #1 ...". I think that because of your comment on XPD's answer: "Existing networking authenticated sessions do not follow you when you elevate."

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be in setting the title bar of an Open/SaveFileDialog instance. Looks like there is a path that cannot be accessed by the this app. It could be a resource file that is used to set the title of this file dialog. Give the necessary directory and file permissions to the users.

Comment: Is there any way I can find out what file is missing those permissions? As far as I know the users have full control permissions for all of the network share.

Comment: @ChrisParker does the program elevate itself for UAC before it runs?

Comment: Yes, it runs with Admin privileges.

Comment: Existing networking authenticated sessions do not follow you when you elevate. You need to re-authenticate with any network shares (i.e. If you had to manually type in a username and password to get to the share to start the program, you have to type the username and password again as a elevated process (however you don't get the opportunity to enter a username and password when it is first displayed so it raises the execption)). If you set the working directory of the program to a local path (see my answer) or you copy the program locally before you run it, it will fix the problem.

Comment: I had that thought originally, but even moving all of the files to the user's desktop still brings up the error. So it must be trying to access a file outside the folder structure, but I'm not sure where. Frustrating.

Comment: Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and search for the path of the permission denied file operation while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what File I/O path it is trying to access in mainForm.vb, and give the relevant users the necessary directory permissions in this path.

Comment: All of the files used in the application are stored on the network share along with the .exe file, and all users have full control permissions for those folders. Could there be something else I'm missing?